# Random crash - what's happening?

Tags: gnome-shell, crash

I'm experiencing random crashes in my Ubuntu 22.10. When it happens, I just click to send the crash report. Apart from that, I can use Ubuntu just fine.

But I would like to understand what is causing this crash, and maybe fix it.

The full crash report is here (80mb): https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApzV_6dERmV3hcpnlSGrYCK4sF9jjg?e=k7bj4X

My system:

```
leodip@pcsubuntu:/var/crash$ inxi -b
System:
  Host: pcsubuntu Kernel: 6.1.4-060104-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: PCSpecialist product: Intel Z790 Ddr5 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX Z690-F GAMING WIFI v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2204
    date: 11/30/2022
CPU:
  Info: 24-core (8-mt/16-st) 13th Gen Intel Core i9-13900K [MST AMCP]
    speed (MHz): avg: 2939 min/max: 800/5500:5800:4300
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] driver: amdgpu
    v: kernel
  Device-3: Logitech C922 Pro Stream Webcam type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon gpu: amdgpu resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~144Hz 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6600 (navi23 LLVM 15.0.2 DRM 3.49
    6.1.4-060104-generic) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.1
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V driver: igc
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 69.82 GiB (3.7%)
Info:
  Processes: 531 Uptime: 13m Memory: 62.55 GiB used: 3.75 GiB (6.0%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.21
leodip@pcsubuntu:/var/crash$
```

I appreciate any help with this :-)